# Node express app disk requirement

Tags: performance, express, solid-state-drive

I have an api (Express.js driven) that doesn't do any disk operation. It only reads/writes to db. Would there be a difference if the machine runs an ssd type of disk or standard disk?

Does it influence the performance? Because I believe the require loads files only one time not every request.

Comment: What type of database are you using?

Comment: For the server itself it makes no difference, as it operates in RAM. Does DB run on the same machine? In case of DB I/O operations there could be a slightly performance difference.

Comment: The db (mongo) runs in a different server. It has ssd. So great than. Thank you!